# How to query the Noticed gem json field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using [Noticed](https://github.com/excid3/noticed) gem for my notifications and I am trying to query for the notifications related to the post.
The notification stores the post as an object inside params.

```
#<Notification id: 10, params: {:post=>#<Post id: 3}>
```

I can target like

```
notification.params[:post][:id] 
=> 3
```

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
Notifications.where(params[:post][:id] => 3)
```

Is there a way to do that or my approach should be different?

**Edited:**

Here is an example of a notification in the database:

```
#<Notification id: 10, recipient_type: "User", recipient_id: 8, type: "MessageNotification", params: {:user=>#<User id: 3, email: "test2@test2.com", created_at: "2021-01-06 23:34:46", updated_at: "2021-04-15 17:47:54", admin: true>, :conversation=>#<Mailboxer::Conversation id: 6, subject: "Hello", created_at: "2021-05-14 00:14:41", updated_at: "2021-05-14 00:26:06">}, read_at: nil, created_at: "2021-05-14 00:26:06", updated_at: "2021-05-14 17:11:50">
```

squema.rb

```
t.jsonb "params"
```

A query suggested by @Joel_Blum and the slq call:

```
>> current_user.notifications.where('params @> ?', {conversation: {id: 6}}.to_json).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"notifications\".* FROM \"notifications\" WHERE \"notifications\".\"recipient_id\" = 8 AND \"notifications\".\"recipient_type\" = 'User' AND (params @> '{\"conversation\":{\"id\":6}}')"

Returns => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

Comment: What datatype is `params`? In case it corresponds to a table in your database.

Comment: I am not sure. I think it is a hash. If I try ....params.type I get"undefined method `type' for #<Hash:0x...>"

Comment: See Joel answer, if not you can inspect your db/schema.rb file and see the datatype there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the gem creates either a [jsonb or json column](https://github.com/excid3/noticed/blob/master/lib/generators/noticed/model_generator.rb#L44) depending on your db.
So what want is perform a search on a json(b) column

For postgres for example it can be done like this

```
Notification.where('params @> ?', {post: {id: 3}}.to_json)
```

Comment: I am getting an empty array.  I am sure the id exists though.  I looked in the schema and it says params are jsonb type. Could it be that?

Comment: can you please show the sql being generated?

Comment: I edited the question with the result from the SQL: "SELECT \"notifications\".* FROM \"notifications\" WHERE \"notifications\".\"recipient_id\" = 8 AND \"notifications\".\"recipient_type\" = 'User' AND (params @> '{\"conversation\":{\"id\":6}}')"

Comment: I think I was having a problem with some cashed information. I opened a different browser to send a new message for my conversations and your query worked on the new browser.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason I am getting an empty array on a notification that I am sure exists.

query: `Notification.where('params @> ?', {comment: {id: testc.id}}.to_ json)`

SQL: `"SELECT \"notifications\".* FROM \"notifications\" WHERE (params @> '{\"comment\":{\"id\":656}}')"`

Answer (score 0):

Noticed has a built in way of querying for objects you send in the params.

If you add `has_noticed_notifications` to the Post model, you should then be able to call `@post.notifications_as_post`

This is in the Noticed [readme here](https://github.com/excid3/noticed#associating-notifications). I definitely came here and found this question before I found the details in the readme!