# Rails - Querying Noticed Notification with the params id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jsonb

I have searched through the related questions for example this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539518/how-to-query-the-noticed-gem-json-field) and the solutions marked there doesn't work for me.

So here is my problem:

I want to get a list of notifications that are for a specific recipient, and the notifications have to be made on comments belonging to a specific plant.

Currently I am using ruby to filter but the database hit is not ideal.

Here is the state of my code.

Models:

```
class Plant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notifications, as: :recipient, dependent: :destroy
end

class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_noticed_notifications
end

class CommentNotification < Noticed::Base
  def comment
    params[:comment]
  end
end
```

This is the query I am currently using: `@plant.comments.flat_map { |comment| comment.notifications_as_comment }.filter { |notification| notification.recipient == current_user }.map(&:mark_as_read!)`

Any help is deeply appreciated...

Comment: Do you have `Comment` model?

Comment: Yes, I do. I forgot to add that. I will do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed has a built in helper method for finding notifications based on the params.

If you add `has_noticed_notifications` to the model which you want to search for in the params, `Comment` in your case.

You can then call `@comment.notifications_as_comment` and it will return all notifications where the `@comment` is `params[:comment]`

This is in the Noticed [readme here](https://github.com/excid3/noticed#associating-notifications). I definitely came here and found this question before I found the details in the readme!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by making a comment method and then using that in my filter, it also killed all the excess dB hits I was getting.

```
  def comment_id
    self[:params][:comment].id
  end
```

Then I used this query to arrive at the result, looks cleaner too. Note `comment_ids = @plant.comments.ids`

```
Notification.unread.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
      .filter { |notification| comment_ids.include?(notification.comment_id) }
      .map(&:mark_as_read!)
```